# BibLaTeX Part 2 .... numbers of the Global Bibliography with sort from [1] with refsegment=chapter, sorting=none AND bibstyle=authoryear options

Tags: biblatex, sorting, authoryear

Due to "moewe" I obtined solution for numbering Global biblography with **refsegment=chapter** option. The problem was solved here:

[BibLaTeX and number of the Global Bibliography sort from [1] to [36] with refsegment=chapter and sorting=none options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661836/biblatex-and-number-of-the-global-bibliography-sort-from-1-to-36-with-refseg)

I would like to ask about the same solution but with the option  **bibstyle=authoryear**. When I added authoryear style the nymbers [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661836/biblatex-and-number-of-the-global-bibliography-sort-from-1-to-36-with-refseg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNViF.png) ...etc..[36] disapieared. How to make them to stay with the below settings:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}
    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    
    \usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none,bibstyle=authoryear,refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}
    
    \BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff
    
    \DeclareSortingTemplate{none}{
      \sort{\field{presort}}
      \sort{\citeorder}
      \sort{\intciteorder}
    }
    
    \DeclareSourcemap{
      \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
          \pertype{book}
          \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=aa]
        }
        \map{
          \pertype{article}
          \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=bb]
        }
        \map{
          \pertype{online}
          \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=cc]
        }
        \map{
          \pertype{inproceedings}
          \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=dd]
        }
      }
    }
    
    \defbibheading{subsubbibintoc}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}} 
    \defbibheading{subsubbibliography}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}}  
    
    \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
    
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    
    Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
    ipsum \autocite{nietzsche:ksa1}
    dolor \autocite{moraux}
    sit \autocite{knuth:ct:c}~\autocite{spiegelberg}.
    
    \printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]
    
    \vspace{5mm}
    {\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Chapter 2}}
    
    Lorem~\cite{vizedom:related}
    ipsum~\cite{gerhardt}
    dolor~\cite{augustine}
    sit~\cite{ctan}.
    
    \printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]
    
    \vspace{5mm}
    {\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Chapter 3}}
    
    Lorem~\cite{wassenberg},
    ipsum~\cite{baez/online}.
    
    \printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]
    
    \printbibheading[title=Global bibliography at the end,heading=bibintoc]
    \printbibliography[type=book,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Books}]
    \printbibliography[type=article,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Articles}]
    \printbibliography[type=online,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Online}]
    \printbibliography[type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Conferences}]
    
    \end{document}
```

The current situation.

[image]

Regards,

LF

Comment: `bibstyle=authoryear,` does not have numbers, because it is supposed to be used with citation styles of the same family. There are ways to get a numeric bibliography with authoryear. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I have seen this possibility (let call it "dirty trick") but I was wondering whether there is some "clear" "system" solution. If it is only one possibilities it is OK. It works. I  will give maybe one o two more another questions. First is reffering to the  warrinings. HOw do I can off them. I know that beter is let them be acctibve but I need such a possibility in case I know I have 100% well done my job with a few acceptable warnings then when I OFF them and appear again another I have an info that something bad is going with my job.  I will ask the separate question Part 3.

Comment: Well, there are other ways to obtain the same effect, but they will probably take more than the three lines suggested in the linked answer. (The second answer has a suggestion that needs only one line, but there are alignment issues with it.)

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate. In case anyone comes across this question here and wants to propose an alternative solution, they can head over to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864 and add their answer there.