# Suppress empty bibliography warnings

Tags: biblatex, warnings

I have solution (due to "moewe") for my specific problem of sorting in BiBLaTeX and numbering.

[BiBLaTeX Part 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661836/biblatex-and-number-of-the-global-bibliography-sort-from-1-to-36-with-refseg)
and
[BiBLaTeX Part 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662889/biblatex-part-2-numbers-of-the-global-bibliography-with-sort-from-1-with)

The both problems has been solved like below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,language=english, style=numeric, ,citestyle=numeric,giveninits=true,dashed=false,
bibstyle=authoryear,refsegment=chapter,backref=true]{biblatex}


\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff


\DeclareSortingTemplate{none}{
  \sort{\field{presort}}
  \sort{\citeorder}
  \sort{\intciteorder}
}


\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{book}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=aa]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=bb]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{online}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=cc]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{inproceedings}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=dd]
    }
  }
}
\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}                         
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{family-given}                         
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}


\defbibheading{subsubbibintoc}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}} 
\defbibheading{subsubbibliography}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}}  

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}

Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nietzsche:ksa1}
dolor \autocite{moraux}
sit \autocite{knuth:ct:c}~\autocite{spiegelberg}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\vspace{5mm}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Chapter 2}}

Lorem~\cite{vizedom:related}
ipsum~\cite{gerhardt}
dolor~\cite{augustine}
sit~\cite{ctan}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\vspace{5mm}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Chapter 3}}

Lorem~\cite{wassenberg},
ipsum~\cite{baez/online}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\printbibheading[title=Global bibliography at the end,heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[type=article,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[type=online,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Conferences}]

\end{document}
```

Using the code I have 6 warnings"

[image]

It should be like that because it gives me the info that in some Chapter I didn't use articles for example etc. Majority of the users (including moewe - thank you again)  just accept the warnings...me too...but I need a possibility to **OFF** such a warnings and simple:

```
\usepackage {silence}
\WarningFilter  {biblatex}{Empty bibliography on input line 65.}
```

doesn't work because there is page number different in any time...etc.

My explanation why I need it. For instance in case when I know that I have 100% well done my job or I share my job with someone else and I have knowledge that there are a few acceptable warnings (my job is ready) I make the **OFF** all warnings and continue my job. So instead of keeping track of whether there are some new warnings among many of the old ones I just **OFF** them all and when appear again others I have an info that something **WRONG** is going with my job. The make **OFF** this specific warnings is a challenge for me then I ask about some help.

Comment: `\WarningFilter` does not need a full message, you can provide only the first part of the sentence and then it will match all warnings that start with that part. So `\WarningFilter{biblatex}{Empty bibliography on input line}` will suppress all six warnings at once.

Comment: I have done it and had tried before. **Doesn't work** :(. I can sent printscreen from my compilation. It works wit word latex and only Empty like **\WarningFilter  {latex}{Empty}**  but I am afride that I can **OFF** alll warnings with "Empty" word at the begining :(???

Comment: I just tried it and you are right, `\WarningFilter{biblatex}{Empty bibliography on input line}` does not work. `\WarningFilter{biblatex}{Empty bibliography}` does work though, that may be a good compromise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Empty bibliography}
```

or

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@warn@bibempty{}
\makeatother
```

(the latter only works after `biblatex` is loaded).

With the former we use the `silence` package to filter out the warning. Perhaps unexpectedly `biblatex` does not issue the empty bibliography warning under its own name, but rather produces a generic LaTeX warning (presumably it replicates the standard behaviour of BibTeX-generated bibliographies to make it easier for tools that parse the `.log` output to see what's going on), so we need `\WarningFilter{latex}` and not `\WarningFilter{biblatex}`. Additionally, the filter text cannot contain the `on line ...` message, because that it added automatically by LaTeX and not seen by the message filtering code.

The second solution works by telling the macro that issues the relevant warning on the `biblatex` side to do nothing. Generally, `biblatex` does not always have a dedicated macro for all warnings available, but here you were lucky.

Comment: I will prepare (I think the last problem which will be copleted my problems I think). To the all above example I need to show at the last page the same Global bibliography (taking under condition that previous one is active and we see Global bib divided on books, articles, etc...this last part would be easy cancel division) but just with alphabetic order and numered without any groups like books etc. I will prepare Parte 4. I mut think in which way to number I would like 1-32 but it wouldn't have any sense refering to the previouse one - the goal is alphabetic order. Maybe I will try myself.